# Distinct objects from property GS collections Java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, gs-collections

Assume that I have a list (GS Collections) of Customers with two properties: id and age, I want apply a distinct filter to the property id

```
 FastList<Customer> customers ...
 customers.distinct( ) //Hey here there's no overload to provide a custom comparator!
```

Comment: A class from GS Collections

Comment: Do you want a collections of distinct ids or a collection of distinct customers?

Comment: @Craig  Distinct customers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `distinct()` and `toSet()` is that `distinct()` will preserve order
from the original list, but both rely on the default object equality using `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

The method `toSortedSet()` takes a `Comparator`, and `toSortedSetBy()` allows you to just pass in a `Function`. Both should work for you. Here's how `toSortedSetBy()` looks using Java 8.

```
FastList<Customer> customers = ...;
MutableSortedSet<Customer> sortedSet = customers.toSortedSetBy(Customer::getId);
```

There are two drawbacks of using a `SortedSetIterable`. The first is that the algorithm is O(n log n) instead of O(n). The second is that the `SortedSetIterable` will behave strangely if its equals method is inconsistent with the comparator (Customer.equals() doesn't consider two Customers equals even if they have the same id).

The second approach is to use a `UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy`.

```
FastList<Customer> customers = FastList.newListWith(c1, c2, c3);
UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy<Customer> set =
  new UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy<>(HashingStrategies.fromIntFunction(Customer::getId));
set.addAll(customers);
```

This runs in O(n) time, but you lose ordering. GS Collections doesn't have a form of `distinct()` that takes a `HashingStrategy`, but you could write it on your own.

```
public static <T> FastList<T> distinct(
        FastList<T> fastList, 
        HashingStrategy<T> hashingStrategy)
{
  MutableSet<T> seenSoFar = 
          UnifiedSetWithHashingStrategy.newSet(hashingStrategy);
  FastList<T> targetCollection = FastList.newList();
  for (int i = 0; i < fastList.size(); i++)
  {
    if (seenSoFar.add(fastList.get(i)))
    {
      targetCollection.add(fastList.get(i));
    }
  }
  return targetCollection;
}
```

And you use it like this.

```
distinct(customers, HashingStrategies.fromIntFunction(Customer::getId));
```

Comment: Good answer!, but I still believe that an overloaded method distinct is missing, one that accepts a Comparator or a HashingStrategy

Comment: You're correct. The example that I wrote that takes a HashingStrategy as a parameter could be generalized and put on ListIterable as an overload, and I think we should consider doing so in a future version of GS Collections. A version that takes a Comparator could be confusing, so I'd want to be more careful.